# combining classes in vba?

Tags: class, vba

I have a problem finding the right structure of my programme and I am trying to solve it using classes, without success.

I have 1 class for Patients, each Patient has the following:

- Name
- Operation
- Surgeon
- OperationDuration

Then each Surgeon should have a schedule for everyday.

Therefore, I am thinking using another class for daily schedule, which should have :

- Day
- TotalDuration

Something in my thinking doesn't look correct and I am struggling to understand what should I do.

1)Is my structure correct for what I want to do?

2)How can I check if a surgeon has a planned daily schedule and if he doesn't then add a patient to his schedule?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
George

---

### Class Patients

```
Private mstrName As String
Private mstrOperationDescription As String
Private mlngSurgeon As Long
Private mdblOpDuration As Double


Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mstrName
End Property

Public Property Get OperationDescription() As String
    OperationDescription = mstrOperationDescription
End Property

Public Property Get Surgeon() As Long
    Surgeon = mlngSurgeon
End Property

Public Property Get OpDuration() As Double
    OpDuration = mdblOpDuration
End Property
```

## Class Schedule

```
Private mlngDay As Long
Private mdblTotalDuration As Double


Public Property Get Day() As Long
    Day = mlngDay
End Property

Public Property Let Day(ByVal lDay As Long)
    mlngDay = lDay
End Property

Public Property Get TotalDuration() As Double
    TotalDuration = mdblTotalDuration
End Property

Public Property Let TotalDuration(ByVal dTotalDuration As Double)
    mdblTotalDuration = dTotalDuration
End Property
```

### Test Sub calculating the total duration but I am not able to list them according to days count

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim mydata As New clsData
Dim schedule1 As New clsSchedule
Dim schedule2 As New clsSchedule
Dim i As Integer

mydata.InputData

For i = 1 To mydata.PatientCount

    If mydata.patient(i).Surgeon = 1 Then

        schedule1.TotalDuration = schedule1.TotalDuration + mydata.patient(i).OpDuration

    Else
        schedule2.TotalDuration = schedule2.TotalDuration + mydata.patient(i).OpDuration

    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Total Duration is: " & schedule1.TotalDuration


End Sub
```

Comment: +1 - Good question. Perhaps you can look into Class Chaining to achieve this.

Comment: Tried and it didn't help me to understand how I can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a Collection of Surgeon objects and a Collection of Patient objects. Each Patient has a Surgeon as a property, and each Surgeon has a Collection of Patients.

From this you can find out the total operation duration across all patients belonging to a Surgeon.

The trick is to know how the objects relate to each other - in this case each Patient has one Surgeon, and each Surgeon can have many Patients. This leads quite logically to the following structure:

## Patient

```
Private mstrName As String
Private mstrOperationDescription As String
Private mobjSurgeon As cSurgeon
Private mdblOpDuration As Double


Property Let Name(txt As String)
    mstrName = txt
End Property

Property Let OperationDescription(txt As String)
    mstrOperationDescription = txt
End Property

Property Let Surgeon(objSurgeon As cSurgeon)
    Set mobjSurgeon = objSurgeon
End Property

Property Let OpDuration(num As Double)
    mdblOpDuration = num
End Property
Property Get OpDuration() As Double
    OpDuration = mdblOpDuration
End Property
```

## Surgeon

```
Private mstrName As String
Private mlngSurgeonId As Long
Private mcolPatients As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolPatients = New Collection
End Sub

Property Let Name(txt As String)
    mstrName = txt
End Property
Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mstrName
End Property

Property Let IdNumber(num As Long)
    mlngSurgeonId = num
End Property
Property Get IdNumber() As Long
    IdNumber = mlngSurgeonId
End Property

Sub AddPatient(objPatient As cPatient)
    mcolPatients.Add objPatient, objPatient.Name
End Sub

Function TotalHours() As Double
    
    Dim objPatient As cPatient
    For Each objPatient In mcolPatients
        TotalHours = TotalHours + objPatient.OpDuration
    Next objPatient
    
End Function
```

## Test Routine

```
Sub CheckSurgeonHours()

    Dim colSurgeons As Collection
    Set colSurgeons = New Collection
    
    Dim colPatients As Collection
    Set colPatients = New Collection
    
    'Populate Surgeon and Patient collections from input data
    'This is the static data for each object, i.e. name, Id, operation type/duration
    
    Dim objSurgeon As cSurgeon
    For Each objSurgeon In colSurgeons
    
        Dim objPatient As cPatient
        For Each objPatient In colPatients
            
            objPatient.Surgeon = objSurgeon
            objSurgeon.AddPatient objPatient
        
        Next objPatient
    
        Debug.Print objSurgeon.TotalHours
    
    Next objSurgeon

End Sub
```